# UWP: When are controls declared final/sealed?

Tags: c#, uwp, c++-cx, c++-winrt

What factors determine whether the MS developers disallow inheritance from a control? (I'm assuming there are some common underlying reasons?)

Perusing the Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls namespace, I don't see any mention or obvious pattern as to why some controls are declared with the `final`/`sealed` specifier while others aren't. Certainly, someone, somewhere must have wanted to derive from, say, TextBlock, only to be disappointed. But why forbid this behavior? What makes a control like Image final but not MediaTransportControls?

Comment: WinRT runs on COM, which does not support implementation inheritance so final/sealed is normal.  It can be emulated with aggregation, in WinRT that requires a "composition factory interface".  MediaTransportControls has one (IMediaTransportControlFactory), Image does not.  It is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/winrt-cref/winrt-type-system#runtime-classes), beware the high gobbledegook factor.

Comment: @HansPassant Interesting. So by that token, what I'm really asking is, why do some controls implement a composition factory interface while others to not?